# Fetch docker container name of microservices registered with the Eureka server

Tags: spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Does the Eureka server have information on container image names for registered applications? I am working on a spring-boot microservices application in which it is necessary to get image names during registration or subsequent health checks. Eureka server can provide a lot of information about the application registered (using the `InstanceInfo` object), but there is no information such as container/image name. Or would it be possible to query application metadata for such information? Or is there any other approach that can be used in achieving this task?